# C: Time Limit Exceeded in while-loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

I have written following code with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, quadr, sum;
    i = 0;
    quadr = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while (i < 50);
    {
        quadr = i * i;
        sum = sum + quadr;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("Summe = %d\n", quadr);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it with this IDE: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/FP0bOFBmJf

I get this Runtime Error:

> Time Limit Exceeded

Could you help me find my mistake?

Comment: typo while(i < 50) not while(i < 50); ';'

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` at the end of the line that contains the `while` statement.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: the semicolon `;` that you put after `while(i<50)` makes the `while` block empty, the program will check the condition `i<50` forever because `i` would not change. The block after `while` statement does not belong to it.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove semicolon after while.

From
`while (i < 50);`

To
`while (i < 50)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing originates in the line

```
while (i < 50);
```

and specifically in the semicolon at the end of the statement.
In its current form, when we go over this line, the program will
loop on indefinitely, as there is nothing specified in the
body of the loop. The `i` won't increment.

Fix it by writing

```
while (i < 50) {  /* curly bracket after statement */
  quadr = i * i;
  sum = sum + quadr;
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code leads to an infinite loop, because of the `;` after the `while`. Indeed the part of the code behind the brackets is never executed, so `i` is never incremented.

Replace:

```
while (i < 50);
```

by:

```
while (i < 50)
```